# Decreasing number of partitions reduces execution time

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I want to see how the execution time of my program changes with different number of partitions. I use a machine with 8 cores and 16GB RAM to run my program. When I create my graph edges and vertices by default spark uses 8 partitions (numPartitions) and the time is 11 minutes. However, when I reduce the number of partitions (i.e. `sc.parallelize(edges, X)`) I get the following results:

```
X = 8 (default) -> time = 11 min
X = 4 -> time = 7.4 min
X = 2 -> time = 4.4 min
X = 1 -> time = 3.3 min
```

Can someone explain why that happens? Also, if I run the same program in a  machine with less cores is it certain that the execution time decreases? Is there a chance to remain the same?

Comment: How big is your data?

Comment: The graph is created by 40 texts of average size (1KB each approximately) in a specific way that the resulted graph is larger than the original texts.

Comment: Almost certainly, the exchange of data between partitions is taking more time than you're saving from parallelizing your computation. 40K is tiny, even if the resulting graph is larger. Without more information on the computation and your data, it's impossible to be more specific.

Comment: This is what I imagined. As far as the computation is concerned, I simply map edges, union and aggregateByKey and finally I use union upon the vertices and all of that in a long iteration because each text is a graph and I use these transformations between the graphs.